# Power Automate + SharePoint list - Compose/Get Item operation error

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am currently struggling with a flow almost identical to this one: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Find-Lowest-number-in-list-column-and-use-to-sort-items/td-p/777718

My flow fails at the last *Get Item* operation with following error:

```
Error
Action 'Get_item' failed

Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Get_item' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'outputs('Get_items_2')?['body/value'][outputs('Compose')]['ID']' cannot be evaluated because property '{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "\"4\"",
      "ItemInternalId": "3",
      "ID": 3,
      "Title": "Name Surname",
      "Counter": 11.0, [...]
```

***most of this part of the property info had to be redacted***

```
[...] cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

My flow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically I need to extract this ID (in this case its equal 3) as ID for Get Item and I'm done. I just can't get passed this last line without any errors.

Any advice highly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but it's a bit hard to know what you're doing when the steps in between are black holes.  Firstly, what does the compose do?  I don't know why you need that.  I'll attempt an answer but it may be missing some context so we'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps.  Using this list ...

[image: List]

... with this **VERY** basic concept and expression ...

[image: Flow]

... it produces the expected result.

[image: Result]

Bottom line, I don't think you need the `Compose` action, simply query the `Get items` result set using the following expression ...

```
first(body('Get_items')?['value'])['id']
```

Given you only want 1 record back from the `Get items` call, the above seems to be the easiest way to achieve what you want.

You may need to perform some error checking if `Get items` returns nothing though.

Comment: It did work as expected, thank you Skin!